# generator-angular-fullstack d3.js directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I've alread tested that in a plnkr and it works fine. But whenever i try to use it in a directive inside of the Daftmonk/generator-angular-fullstack it renders everything except the arrows at the end of the links. It works fine when used in main.html...but in every other route is fails...the css is picked up correctly but the svg's are an issue. The arrows for example wont show up.

plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mYRoPVDP95vFw7YkHrAG?p=info

generator:
github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

directive:

```
app.directive('myNodes', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
          var links = [
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
            {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved"},
            {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit"},
            {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
          ];

          var nodes = {};

          // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
          links.forEach(function(link) {
            link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
            link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
          });

          var width = 960,
              height = 500;

          var force = d3.layout.force()
              .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
              .links(links)
              .size([width, height])
              .linkDistance(60)
              .charge(-300)
              .on("tick", tick)
              .start();

          var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

          // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
          svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
              .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
            .enter().append("marker")
              .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
              .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
              .attr("refX", 15)
              .attr("refY", -1.5)
              .attr("markerWidth", 6)
              .attr("markerHeight", 6)
              .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append("path")
              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

          var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
              .data(force.links())
            .enter().append("path")
              .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
              .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

          var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
              .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", 6)
              .call(force.drag);

          var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
              .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("text")
              .attr("x", 8)
              .attr("y", ".31em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

          // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
          function tick() {
            path.attr("d", linkArc);
            circle.attr("transform", transform);
            text.attr("transform", transform);
          }

          function linkArc(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
          }

          function transform(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          }
        }
    };
}]);
```

[(Original Example)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)